# How to run oracle query inside javascript using jsp variable?

Tags: javascript, oracle, jsp

I have a javascript function `onChange()`. When I change my select in dropdown list from JSP page the `onChange()` is called. Now I need to execute a Oracle query inside `onChange` function in that query. I need to use the selected value from the dropdown list in JSP.

How can I make it?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to send a request (using AJAX, for example) to your server.

Comment: You're mismatching server side and client side: JSP and ORACLE DB are on the server side, javascripts run on the client's browser. You'll have to run the query in the server i.e. using a Web-Service

Comment: can you give me any example or tutorial link from where I can get the idea. I'm very new to javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` is executed at client side, and `JSP` is executed at Server side. You cannot do calls between them.

In your case, the `JSP` is generating the script which gets executed at client side. And if you require any server side validations/operations to be done, you should be using `AJAX` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life easier, I suggest you use [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (or a similar library).